# Swift How can I show a video without interruption on reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I am creating a social network app in order to learn swift (using Swift 4) and complete a project . I have a TableView that shows videos and I have added the functionality of 'liking' videos like any social network. My issue is that when you like a video the TableView gets reloaded to show the '+ 1 like' and the Video starts all over again. How can I make it so that the video doesn't restart every time you like a video . This is my code here

1st You get the user clicking the Like Action which s**ends a call to the database and insert the like** and add '+1 to the like field'

```
@IBAction func LikeAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        DontReload = sender.tag

        let url:URL = URL(string:ConnectionString+"insert_like")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        let parameter = "parameters"
        request.httpBody = parameter.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

          self.reloadTable()
            }
            }.resume()


    }
```

Then I query the database and return the new data showing the +1 like and other data in Json Format.

```
func reloadTable() {

    var url = URL(string:ConnectionString+"streams")!

    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    let parameter = "Parameters"
    request.httpBody = parameter.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {

        } else {
            do {

                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]

                if let Streams = parsedData["Results"] as? [AnyObject]?  {
                    // check for misspelled words

                    if streamsModel.Locations.count >= 0 {
                    // Set My Arrays

                    }


                    for Stream in Streams! {

                    // Gets Json Values

                    }

                        TableSource.reloadData()
                    }

                }

                else {


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        streamsModel.Locations.removeAll()
                        TableSource.reloadData()

                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }

        }

    }).resume()

}
```

This is my TableViewCell and this is obviously called to show the new updated data, however if the user is watching a video and likes it while it is playing then the video restarts... any suggestions on solving this would be great.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC

   // Starts Video Plays
                   cell.videoView = cell.VideoViewArray[indexPath.row]
              cell.videoView.tag = indexPath.row
                 let movieURL = URL(string: cell.stream_image_string[indexPath.row])

                 cell.videoCapHeight.constant = CGFloat(Float(cell.pic_height!))
                 cell.playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieURL!)
                 cell.MyAVPlayer.player = cell.playerView
                 cell.MyAVPlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
                 cell.MyAVPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
                 cell.MyAVPlayer.view.frame = cell.videoView.bounds
                 cell.videoView.addSubview(cell.MyAVPlayer.view)
                 controller.addChildViewController(cell.MyAVPlayer)
                 cell.playerView?.isMuted = false
                 cell.MyAVPlayer.player?.play()
               // Ends Video play

        return cell
    }
```

Again my code works the only issue is that my videos restart on Table Reloads . I want to create some type of condition or flag that If a Table View Cell gets 'liked' and there is a video then I want that video to not get reloaded . Any suggestions would be great . Based on suggestions below I will stop using ReloadTable and attempt to grab a reference for that UIButton perhaps something like this

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath()
 let cell = self.TableSource.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HomeTVC
 cell.votes.setTitle("result from server",for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Don't reload the tableview. Get a reference to the cell and update it directly.

Comment: By convention your function should be called `likeAction`, also using the `tag` becomes an issue when your tableview contains sections or supports row insertion/deletion. I believe your code will also have issues whe the tableview scrolls, although maybe you are handling pausing the video before cell reuse in code not shown.

Comment: You don't really need to reaload the TableView.
Get response from the server that a video is liked successfully and update your data source of that index. 
Then get a reference to that cell and update its label.

Comment: Will change the function name to make it conventional. Oh Ok thanks for clarifying. I will stop doing the reload table for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement is seems you don't need to reload whole table view in case of just update like, Once you receive API response of "**insert_like**" You can update your array and directly get reference of your video running cell and update data source of it.